# Questions for Network Analyzing in Perl

Tags: macos, perl, networking, html

I'm planning to make a Network Analyzer for my thesis that utilizes SNMP to receive MAC addresses of hosts connected to a the managed switch. From there, I will get the packets passing through the switch via Port Mirroring, and then analyze it. For this, I will be using Perl. However, I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to scan aggregated switches as well? Let's say my software is running on PC A, which is then connected to the SPAN port of Switch A. Then, Switch A's fa0/10 interface is connected to Switch B's fa0/10. I was told unless both fa0/10's are span ports, you won't be able to get packets from Switch B. Is this right? If not, how will this work?
2. Does Perl support sniffing packets from two multiple NICs simultaneously? Let's say Switch A's SPAN port is connected to NIC A, and Switch B's SPAN port is connected to NIC B. Is there a library in Perl that will allow me to mirror packets from both switches together?

Sorry if any of the questions don't make sense. I'm having a hard time expressing what my confusion as my mind is already cluttered as it is.

Comment: http://www.snort.org/community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Yes, it is true. You need to connect both switches with port mirroring.

2: This technique is called forking/threading/event listening. It is possible using these methods.

Here are some pointers:

- http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/TCP_Port_Redirection
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Sniffer::HTTP